# What does it mean when the Community bot modifies my question?

Tags: support, editing, community

One of my questions has just been bumped onto the front page by the Community bot:

[image: modified]

But the revision histories of [the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/103173/revisions) and [its sole answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/104142/revisions) (no deleted answers) show no activity since several weeks ago.

**What modification was made by the Community bot?**

Comment: The current answers do not answer this: where does the community bot get its in depth knowledge of [Doctor Who](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/1114/revisions)?

Comment: Looking at it a bit more deeply, I see that the community bot only [approved edits by other users](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12550). Finally, a several-year old mystery solved!

Comment: @Wikis Yeah, she owns (approved) edits made by anonymous users

Comment: @Wikis She also, [occasionally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161593/how-did-you-get-community-to-post-a-comment), speaks

Comment: @JasonBaker the bot has a *gender*?!

Comment: @Wikis She seems to [identify as female](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123)

Comment: @Wikis Don't forget her [name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12122/why-was-my-non-programming-question-on-stackoverflow-closed#comment22357_12122)!

Comment: I'm choosing to leave this question open on the basis that the linked question is asking whether or not certain tags should be excluded from the 'system bump'; this question is asking why the bump occurred to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Community bot bumps old posts with low views and no accepted answers occasionally.

[image]

It doesn't change anything, it just wants to help you get more attention.

Answer (score 3):

Every so often the Community user will bump old questions. Quoting from [its user profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community):

> I do things like […] Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

The only “modification” this involves is to change the last modified time in the database, and attribute an empty edit to the user. It doesn’t make any substantive edits to these posts.